# Concat not work phpmyadmin (mysql)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, string-concatenation

i want update my row and concat my string but i have an error with this query

```
UPDATE FILE SET NOMFIC ='supp_'+D_NOMFIC WHERE IdFile = 2
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NOMFIC ='supp_'+D_NOMFIC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE FILE SET NOMFIC = CONCAT('supp_',NOMFIC) WHERE IdFile=2;
```

See the `CONCAT()` function within the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

CONCAT() basically takes as its parameters a list of strings to be concatenated together.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NOMFIC =CONCAT('supp_',D_NOMFIC)

Comment: @Mercer: that works for me fine. You should be doing something else wrong

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'D_NOMFIC' in 'field list'

Comment: @ mercer - it seems to work fine for me here, i just tried it.

Comment: @mercer, you have the field D_NOMFIC in your original question. I'm guessing you just meant NOMFIC. If so, this is what you want:

UPDATE FILE SET NOMFIC = CONCAT('supp_',NOMFIC) WHERE IdFile=2;

Answer (score 0):

You can't concat with + in MySQL. Use `CONCAT('supp_, D_NOMFIC)`,  so it becomes `UPDATE FILE SET NOMFIC = CONCAT('supp_, D_NOMFIC) WHERE IdFile = 2`

For more info see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

You can concat quoted strings like this: `SELECT 'a' 'b' 'c' FROM someTable` though.

Comment: if D_NOMFIC is 'blah' than the result will be 'supp_blah'

Comment: D_NOMFIC doesn't exist? What's the column's name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`UPDATE FILE SET NOMFIC = CONCAT('supp_', D_NOMFIC) WHERE IdFile = 2`

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'D_NOMFIC' in 'field list'

Answer (score -1):

Use `CONCAT` instead:

```
UPDATE FILE SET NOMFIC =CONCAT('supp_',D_NOMFIC) WHERE IdFile = '2'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
update table_name set column_name1=CONCAT(column_name2,'something');
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).